# Як правильно "закохливий" чи "легко-закохуваний" (по аналогії з "легко-займистий") чи "влюбчєвий"?

Tags: значення-слів, вибір-слова

Для визначення "людина, яка схильна закохуватися швидко та часто", як правильно — *закохливий* чи *легко-закохуваний* (по аналогії з *легко-займистий*) чи *влюбчєвий* (начебто русизм, здається чистим варваризмом з російської)?

Чув такі пропозиції: *влюбливий/залюблений*, але мені здається саме дієслово *кохання* є більш питомо українське у значенні love (у порівнянні з *любити*).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

СУМ [пропонує](http://sum.in.ua/s/uljublyvyj): **улю́бливий (влю́бливий)**

> (розмовне) — Той, який легко, швидко закохується.

---

Мені також попередній варіант не подобається тим, що використовує корінь «любити» замість «кохати». Тому, в якості експерименту, **(увага, не словникове слово!)** можна спробувати вживати:
**Легкозакохуваний** (без дефісу).

СУМ у статті до слова *легко* [додає](http://sum.in.ua/s/leghko):

> **ЛЕГКО...** Перша частина складних слів, що відповідає слову *легкий* у 1, 3 знач., напр.: *легковимовний*.

Значення (1) і (3) формулюються так:

(1) Без фізичного напруження, не докладаючи великих зусиль.
(3) Без ускладнення; просто; Без великого розумового напруження; Досить вільно, природно, невимушено

Comment: В певному контексті, мабуть, може бути [ВЕЛЕЛЮ́БНИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/veleljubnyj) 
ВЕЛЕЛЮ́БНИЙ, а, е, книжн. Здатний глибоко любити кого-, що-небудь або багатьох. Він [Байрон] ненавидів їх [англійських аристократів] всіма силами своєї велелюбної душі (Літературна газета, 17.IV 1939, 1); 
//  ірон. Який прикривається почуттям любові для досягнення певної мети. Велелюбний душпастир.. щойно привернув їх з невірного православ'я в вірну католицьку релігію (Юрій Смолич, Мир.., 1958, 112).
Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 1, 1970. — Стор. 317.

Comment: Легкозакохуваний подобоється й дуже :) Тепер тіко в маси треба пустить і почати використовувати.

Answer (score 9):

В певному контексті, мабуть, може бути [ВЕЛЕЛЮ́БНИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/veleljubnyj)

> **ВЕЛЕЛЮ́БНИЙ**, а, е, книжн. Здатний глибоко любити кого-, що-небудь або
>   багатьох. Він [Байрон] ненавидів їх [англійських аристократів] всіма
>   силами своєї велелюбної душі (Літературна газета, 17.IV 1939, 1); //
>   ірон. Який прикривається почуттям любові для досягнення певної мети.
>   Велелюбний душпастир.. щойно привернув їх з невірного православ'я в
>   вірну католицьку релігію (Юрій Смолич, Мир.., 1958, 112).

Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 1, 1970. — Стор. 317.

Хоча, очевидно, слова *влюбливий* і *велелюбний* не тотожні за значенням. Адже є певні відтінки між "легко/швидко/часто закохуватись" і "любити глибоко або багатьох".